# MvvmCross vnext: CheckBox CheckedChange event to a command with monodroid

Tags: windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to bind CheckedChange from monodroid CheckBox to a command, but I get an error.

I want to unselect another item when a particular one is checked.

I think it is possible to do it with EventTrigger in wp7, but MvvmCross for android doesn't seem to support this feature.

Is MvvmCross limited to Button only ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CheckedChanged` is an `EventHandler<CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs>` so it isn't one of the delegate types that MvvmCross automatigically knows about.

---

However, there is a custom binding in place for this...

https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxCompoundButtonCheckedTargetBinding.cs

And this custom binding should be registered using:

```
registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxSimplePropertyInfoTargetBindingFactory(typeof(MvxCompoundButtonCheckedTargetBinding), typeof(CompoundButton), "Checked"));
```

in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs

---

So if you have a ViewModel with a property `IsSpecial`

```
private bool _isSpecial;
public bool IsSpecial
{
   get { return _isSpecial; }
   set 
   {
      _isSpecial = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsSpecial);
       // your custom code here
   }
}
```

then this binding should work:

```
  'Checked':{'Path':'IsSpecial'}
```

And that should work for any CompoundButton - CheckBox, Switch, or your own compounds...

Comment: I wanted to use an ICommand instead of this property.Nevermind, I changed my ViewModel to solve the problem.

Comment: You can write a custom binding if you prefer... Or you could bind click to some sort of toggle command?

Comment: Instead of CheckedChange event, I use Click event and it works with my command. I prefer this design instead of playing with a property binding or write a new custom binding for now. Many thanks.

Comment: @Stuart `CompoundButton` doesn't work. While registering I tried to change the type to `CheckBox` - `typeof(CheckBox)` and it just worked fine.

Comment: if you've got a problem with the answer, please edit it. If you've got a bug in mvx, please log it on issues - with extra bonus smilies if you include a git repo where I can repro it :) Thanks. Stuart

Comment: Looks like this is no longer required as it is now part of the framework.